# Encapsulated PostScript files in TexShop

Tags: texshop, eps

Error message:

```
LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .eps"
```

Graphics command:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \includegraphics[ ]{graphics/"new checkers order M 0200.eps"} 
\end{figure}
```

Unsuccessful variants:

```
  \includegraphics[ ]{graphics/"new checkers order M 0200"} 
  \includegraphics[ ]{graphics/"new checkers order M 0200".eps}
```

File header:

```
\documentclass[conference]{worldcomp}

\usepackage[hmargin=.75in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{caption}

%%% Recommended to use for better results and compatible with the worldcomp.cls
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}   %%% <==========
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % Fixing numbering problem when using figure/table* 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
```

Using TeXShop v 3.51 with Typeset flags `LaTeX` and `PdfTex`. Distribution: TeXLive-2014, Intel 64.

The PDF versions from Mathematica have inferior typesetting and EPS fixes the problem. How can I use the EPS files?

====== addendum: EPS vs PDF

The top figure is the eps version, notice the label for the dependent parameter. In the subsequent PDF version the letter "a" collides with the absolute value operator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What `TeX` distribution are you using? Whichever it is, you should delete `\usepackage{epsfig}`.

Comment: Convert the .eps files to .pdf.

Comment: @Bernard: The pdf files are lower quality than the eps versions.

Comment: @Ian: `epsfig` package call deleted. Malady persists.

Comment: I meant convert *yourself* the .eps  to .pdf. Personally I can see no difference, at least for converting .eps files produced with `pstricks`. A lua script like `epspdf`makes an excellent job, with te help of `ghostscript`. Maybe there are problems if the `.eps` is actually a bitmap graphic file, converted to postscript. For true vector graphics, I don't think there's a difference.

Comment: If youabsolutely want to include .epd files, you'll have to follow the way `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf`, not `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Bernard: manual conversion from eps to pdf. Yes, this works using "Save As..." in Preview. Thanks.

Comment: @Bernard --- if the OP is using a modern installation the figures should be converted to `pdf` on the fly by `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Ian: automatic conversion was the expected result. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: To get this resolved I've duped: the linked question is more generally about graphics formats but does mention auto-conversion.